# Convergence in $l^p$ space?

Tags: convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

We know that $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_{n}^{k} = b_n$.
All $(a_{n}^{k}) \in l^p$ space.
How to show that
$(\lim_{k \to \infty} a_{1}^{k},\lim_{k \to \infty} a_{2}^{k},...,\lim_{k \to \infty} a_{n}^{k},...) = (b_1,b_2,...,b_n,...)$

Answer (score 1):

It is not true in general that convergence in $\ell^p$ takes place: take $a_n^k=0$ if $n\neq k$ and $1$ otherwise.

However, if the remainders are uniformly convergent to $0$, that is, 
$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\sup_{k\geqslant 1}\sum_{n=N}^{+\infty}|a_n^k|^p=0,$$
then the convergence in $\ell^p$ holds by an approximation argument.

Comment: The first point I don't get it. To each n, $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty}$ has already passed the n position.

Comment: Yes, so the limit in each coordinate is $0$, while the $p$-norm of the sequence is $1$.

Comment: The p-norm of sequence $a_n$ is 1, but it seems have no influence on the sequence $b = (b_1,b_2,....)$. It looks like p-norm of b is 0.

Comment: Yes, in this case $b=0$.